# titles and title's tags fetch with function

Tags: php, mysql

i want to fetch titles and title's tags.

```
public function titles()
{
     $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM title");
     while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)){
          $data->title[] = $row;
          $data->tag[] = $this->tags($row->id);
     }
     return $data;
}

public function tags($title_id)
{
     $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tag WHERE title_id = '$title_id'");
     while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)){
           $tag[] = $row;
     }
     return $tag;
}
```

I'm trying to print in this way

```
$data = titles();
foreach($data->title as $title)
{
     echo $title->topic;
     foreach($data->tag as $tag)
     {
         echo $tag->name;
     }
}
```

but it doesnt work. How can I do?
thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have something like this in your titles method

```
$data = new stdClass();
$data->title = array();
$data->tag = array();
```

You also need to add files like this

```
$data->title[$row->id][] = $row;
$data->tag[$row->id][] = $this->tags($row->id);
```

Then you can loop like this

```
foreach($data->title as $id => $title)
{
    echo $title->topic;
    foreach($data->tag[$id] as $tag)
    {
        echo $tag->name;
    }
}
```

Also Enable error so that you can see PHP Errors .. at on top of your page

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors","On");
```

PHP DOC ON `mysql_***`

> Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include

What i think your code should look like

```
class Somthing {
    private $db;

    function __construct() {
        $this->db = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "db");
    }

    function titles() {
        $data = new stdClass();
        $data->title = array();
        $data->tag = array();

        $result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM title");
        while ( $row = $result->fetch_object() ) {
            $data->title[$row->id] = $row;
            $data->tag[$row->id] = $this->tags($row->id);
        }
        return $data;
    }

    function tags($title_id) {
        $tag = array();
        $result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tag WHERE title_id = '$title_id'");
        while ( $row = $result->fetch_object() ) {
            $tag[] = $row;
        }
        return $tag;
    }
}

$somthing = new Somthing();

foreach ($somthing->titles() as $id => $title ) {
    echo $title->topic;
    foreach ( $data->tag[$id] as $tag ) {
        echo $tag->name;
    }
}
```

Comment: A last request :) This process is usually done this way? Or is there a better way?

Comment: @ISM  there would always be a better way .. but this is a good way to start :)